# creating an array of financial time series objects

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a couple of fints, how do I preallocate a cell array so that I can loop through them later? I don't really care if they are stored as a cell array or array or anything different, I just want to be able to do the following

```
for(i = 1:size(stocks))
    figure(i);
    plot(stocks(i));
end
```

or something equivalent. allocating with stocks = zeros(0,5) works great first, but doesn't work when I try to insert the fints because it is assumes it is a double. How would you even go about preallocating arrays for financial time series obejcts? Since it would be different lenghts everytime you insert a new one.

Answer (score 3):

From the Matlab's doc on [Preallocate Memory for a Cell Array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocate-memory-for-a-cell-array.html)

> Cell arrays do not require completely contiguous memory. However, each
>   cell requires contiguous memory, as does the cell array header that
>   MATLAB® creates to describe the array. For very large arrays,
>   incrementally increasing the number of cells or the number of elements
>   in a cell results in Out of Memory errors.
>
> Initialize a cell array by calling the cell function, or by assigning
>   to the last element. For example, these statements are equivalent:

```
C = cell(25,50); C{25,50} = [];
```

> MATLAB creates the header for a
>   25-by-50 cell array. However, MATLAB does not allocate any memory for
>   the contents of each cell.

Comment: I only need a one dimensional array (a list). Is it enough to write C=cell(50) or should i write C = cell(1,50)?

Comment: @user1661303 `cell(50)` produces a 50x50 cell array.  Use either `cell(1,50)` or `cell(50,1)`.  Both are addressable using linear indexing: `Z=cell(1,50); Z{1} = ...; etc. ; Z{50} = ...;`

Comment: result = cell(1,50);
    fin = fints(dates,data, 'Adj_Close','u', symbol);
    result(i) = fin;

produces a "??? In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B
must be the same." error

Comment: @user1661303 With `result = cell(1,50)`,  `result(1) = {10}` and `result{1} = 10` produces the same results (beware of the curly brackets!)